# How to obtain day of the week from date variable

Tags: jmeter

```
{
    "DayNumber": 3,
    "RecurringOn": "1",
    "StartTime": "2024-03-20 14:18",
    "EndTime": "2024-03-20 14:48"
}
```

I'm using above record for my post method and using variables e.g. for start time and end time `(${__timeShift(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm,,PT2M,,)}`.

I need to obtain number of the day from the datetime variable.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) to call [Date.toDayOfWeek()](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#toDayOfWeek()) method allowing you to get the current day of week number (1 for Monday, 3 for Wednesday, etc.)

Full request payload just in case:

```
{
    "DayNumber": ${__groovy(new Date().toDayOfWeek().value,)},
    "RecurringOn": "1",
    "StartTime": "${__timeShift(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm,,PT2M,,time)}",
    "EndTime": "${time}"
}
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)